# Kubernetes on-premise setup?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, kubernetes

I would like to know how to setup a kubernetes cluster on my Ubuntu 20 DPS
I mean, I have installed docker and kubeadm
I know how to make a deployment, service and little of ingress, I have used an already configured kubernetes cluster (aks)

I need to setup my dps to EXPOSE some web apps (websites, apis, cdn etc)
what steps I need to configure kubernetes? how I expose a certain website on a specific sub dns (for example a 3rd level domain: trd.mysite.com)

Do I need to install some addons like nginx-controller, metallb and flannel?
I don't understand these networks stuff, I am also interested in a course/tutorial
please help me thanks!

EDIT: these are my yamls, for now I simply want to expose a webapp
on the main domain (xxxx.com) then I will add an internal REST api
and another webapp that will use the rest api and exposed on a 3rd level domain (yyy.xxxxx.com)
http://www.mediafire.com/file/c7qwouqri441wek/Kube.zip/file

Comment: can you share a little bit more information on your current configuration? is tht minikube or regular 1-master cluster? what exactly you already configured? in the meanwhile ill start prepare an answer for you

Comment: Hi I have installed docker and kubeadm. I have not run the kubeadm init command because i don't know if i have to specify additional parameters like pods cidr

Comment: if you want I can share my ingress, service and deployment

Comment: dont hesitate ask your questions under my answer. cant promise i will be fast in reply, but for sure Ill back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so look. To be able successfully run server you will need:

**1.** [docker](https://www.docker.com/)

**2.** If you prefer install using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/) - you need below Kubernetes packages. We discuss in this answer only kubeadm way. Please reach  internal documentation itself for other tools.

- [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/)
- [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/)
- [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)

Otherwise you can use eg [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/), [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray), [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/). I like minikube and kind.

- kind is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes”.
  kind was primarily designed for testing Kubernetes itself, but may be used for local development or CI.
- MiniKube isusually the first Kubernetes technology found when someone wants to begin (Kubernetes official documentation offers a tutorial to deploy your first cluster using miniKube).
  It is a very simple solution to install on your laptop and it is designed for learning and testing. When started, it will deploy a single node cluster (the smallest size).

You can read about  all the tools here:

- [MiniKube, Kubeadm, Kind, K3S, how to get started on Kubernetes?](https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/minikube-kubeadm-kind-k3s)
- [Is there major difference between Minikube and Kind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585933/is-there-major-difference-between-minikube-and-kind)

**3.** [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) - for proper networking inside your cluster.

There are dozen of CNI plugins, you should chose something.

- Full list is here: [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)
- comparison table: https://kubedex.com/kubernetes-network-plugins/

The most popular one are Flannel and Calico. Sometimes(depend on your needs), you can install [Canal](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/flannel/flannel). In short - you are installing simultaneously Calico for [Network Policies](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/flannel/flannel) + Flannel as a regular CNI for networking.

Here is the important tip! To install CNI correctly - you should chose it in advanxce prior to cluster creation. That s because you have to init cluster with proper `--pod-network-cidr=` flag.

- `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` for Flannel
- `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` for Calico

4. [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers)

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a
> cluster, typically HTTP.
>
> Ingress may provide load balancing, SSL termination and name-based
> virtual hosting.

In order for the Ingress resource to work, the cluster must have an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) running.

Full list of different ingress controllers: [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers). Comparison matrix is [here](https://kubevious.io/blog/post/comparing-top-ingress-controllers-for-kubernetes)

the most popular ones: [Nginx Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), Kubernetes ingress controller(OOB, based also on nginx. But these are diff ones), Traefik

---

**Steps to create the cluster:**

- You can use following excellent article [Single node Kubernetes setup](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/techblog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-setup.html). Start from it - it  shows you all the steps correctly.
- you can use my answer: [Kubernetes api server is not starting on a single kubeadm cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720380/kubernetes-api-server-is-not-starting-on-a-single-kubeadm-cluster/52724543#52724543). This answer  provides you detailed step-by-step instruction how to spin up cluster using kubeadm.
  One note.
- official documentation: [Creating a cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

**You should Untaint the master so you can run pods on it. Without this you wont be able to run pods on your master.**

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Comment: after reinstalling everything
I get 502 badgateway with my deployment.
I have also noticed this when getting all services (pending external ip on ingress nginx): ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.105.95.172    <pending>     80:32226/TCP,443:30537/TCP   20m

Answer (score 0):

**before reading all this, look into kubespray which uses ansbile to create clusters for you however if you want to know how kubernetes works under the hood follow the rest of the answer.**

first step to setting up a kubernetes cluster is knowing the components and how they work
simply installing kubeadm wont spin up a cluster, you should install every component required for your needs before deploying you yaml files.

here is a github page link, it uses kubeadm to spin up and entire kubernetes cluster with 3 master nodes and as many worker nodes as you want.
note: it uses older versions but it is a good reference for learning kubernetes components. make sure you inspect his scripts regarding yaml creation for important cluster components and also read the cluster component specifics on what they do.
https://github.com/cookeem/kubeadm-ha/blob/master/v1.11/README.md
if you want to expose web apps on your cluster on a domain you need to install ingress controller manager which allows you to create ingress resources.
here is an ingress yaml example from kubernetes docs
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
if you want to do https with valid certificates you can use kubernetes secrets or configure cert manager on your cluster for automatic lets encrypt acquisition and renewal
both these options are well documented and all you need to do is do a google search to find how to make your ingress resource use these certificates
make sure your domain points to the public ip address of one cluster node (worker or master)

metallb is used with on premise clusters to provide the load balancer service type  that cloud providers have build-in

flannel is a network plugin providing networking for your cluster
if you want your pods to be able to talk to each other you should have a network plugin cni such as flannel, calico or any other supported plugin
think of flannel as the network switch of you cluster